# Looking for extension to duplicate entire projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, copy, duplicates, visual-studio-2015

Me and my brother are trying to learn C# together. We are trying to follow a guide to do a simple RPG tex-based game.

But we dont always have the possibility to do it together. So I was thinking of making a duplicate of the entire program, and go at it alone. When my brother later could join, I could just simply go back to the original project.

This has turned out to not be as simple as I would hope. There are guides to do this on this very site, but the ones that seem to be working the best feels very complicated and contain many many steps. Since I am a beginner I have a hard time following the logic of it all.

Is there ANY type of extension or upgrade to Visual studio that simply lets you have the option to "Duplicate Project to other folder". That would be ideal!

As I've said, I have searched a while for this on google and whatnot, but couldn't find anything satisfactory. Hope you can help!

Thanks
//Simon

**/EDIT/**

I now realized that the copying wasn't the real issue. The problem is RENAMING your folders. Visual studio doesn't like you to move around stuff and renaming them and it makes it a hassle to fix it.

But as long as I just open one project in one folder when I'm programming with my brother and the other project in another folder and dont mix them up, I should be fine

Thanks for your help tough.

Comment: Copy+paste entire folder from Windows explorer?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing part of your question. You can simply copy and paste the entire project folder into a different directory.

Comment: I have now edited my question with the real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for. I could have commented but you said you where new so I hope the instructions are simple enough to follow:

1. In Visual Studiom, open up solution explorer, usually located on the right
2. Right click the solution name, which should be the very first item on the list
3. Select "Open Folder in File Explorer"
4. Select all the items in the folder and copy them, a simple Ctrl + A and then Ctrl + C should work
5. Go up one level
6. Create a new folder, say "RPGMyCopy"
7. Enter the new folder and then paste
8. Double click on the solution file .sln file

Thats it, you're working on a new copy.

Comment: Great I will try this and see how it goes! :)

Comment: See my added edit on my initial question. Although thank you, because if I didn't try your super-simplified way, I wouldn't have realized what the real problem was. ^^

Comment: You should consider using a code repository like GIT. If you choose GIT, I would strongly consider also using GIT Extensions. Basically you would create a repository, then create a branch just for you to work on.